# Find four,whose sum equals to target

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, binary-search

**Problem:**

Given an array nums of n integers, return an array of all the unique quadruplets [nums[a], nums[b], nums[c], nums[d]] such that:

```
0 <= a, b, c, d < n
a, b, c, and d are distinct.
nums[a] + nums[b] + nums[c] + nums[d] == target
```

You may return the answer in any order.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,0,-1,0,-2,2], target = 0
Output: [[-2,-1,1,2],[-2,0,0,2],[-1,0,0,1]]

Example 2:

Input: nums = [2,2,2,2,2], target = 8
Output: [[2,2,2,2]]

Constraints:

```
1 <= nums.length <= 200
-109 <= nums[i] <= 109
-109 <= target <= 109
```

**Algorithm:**

1. First we sort an array;
2. Pick three different numbers;
3. Find fourth number, which has to equal to `target - num1 - num2 - num3`

.

**C code:**

```
int partition (int *arr, int left, int right) {
    int x = arr[right];
    int i, j;
    i = left - 1;
    for (j = left; j < right; j++)
        if (arr[j] <= x) {
            int tmp = arr[++i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
    arr[right] = arr[++i];
    arr[i] = x;
    return i;
}

void quicksort (int *arr, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int pivot = partition(arr, left, right);
        quicksort(arr, left, pivot - 1);
        quicksort(arr, pivot + 1, right);
    }
}

int** fourSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes) {
    (*returnSize) = 0;
    int **ans = NULL;
    quicksort(nums, 0, numsSize - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize - 3; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize - 2; j++)
            for (int k = j + 1; k < numsSize - 1; k++) {
                int l = target - nums[i] - nums[j] - nums[k];
                int left = k, mid, right = numsSize;
                while (left < right ) {
                    mid = (left + right) / 2;
                    if (nums[mid] < l)
                        left = mid;
                    else if (nums[mid] == l) {
                        (*returnSize)++;
                        ans = realloc(ans, (*returnSize) * sizeof(int));
                        ans[*returnSize - 1][0] = nums[i];
                        ans[*returnSize - 1][1] = nums[j];
                        ans[*returnSize - 1][2] = nums[k];
                        ans[*returnSize - 1][3] = nums[l];
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        right = mid;
                }

            }
        *returnColumnSizes = malloc((*returnSize) * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < (*returnSize); i++)
            (*returnColumnSizes)[i] = 4;
    return ans;
}
```

I thought this is quite optimal solution, but it doesn't even pass time limit.

Comment: Unless the assignment is about implementing your own quicksort, you should use the standard C function `qsort` instead.

Comment: Limits for `target` and array size?

Comment: It is far from optimal.

Comment: I see _four_ levels of nested loops. This is going to scale _very_ poorly, which is likely why it's having problems with the tester on the code challenge website you're using. They're not going to use only small sample sizes. Some of them may have thousands or tens of thousands of numbers to check. Once you start raising large numbers to an exponent, things get out of hand quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small array size allows to create storage for `n*(n-1)/2` pairs (~20000) of structures, containing sum of all possible pairs and corresponding indices

Sort structures by sum value

Then for every sum `S` with `i,j` indices look for pairs with `target-S` and indices distinct from `i,j` (scan sums from the left, corresponding sums from the right)

Overall complexity is `O(n^2*log(n))`

(Also it is possible to use hash table, but there is no in-built hash tables in C)